# multiple vlan bridge with single IP

Tags: vlan

EDIT.

```
[internet]
    |
  [G/W] //ip=192.168.0.1 /24
    |
[switch1] //ip=192.168.0.248, vlan10 G/W =192.168.10.1, vlan20 G/W =192.168.20.1]
    |
 (Tagged)
    |-eno3
 [linux]
    |-eno4
 (Tagged)
    |
[switch2]
    |
  [PCs]
```

switch1 is gateway of VLANs(vlan10, vlan20) (192.168.10.1, 192,168.20.1).

Linux(CentOS7) have interface eno3 and eno4.

eno3 is internet side, eno4 is client side.

I found bridge vlan like 2ways.

1st

```
ip link add br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
ip link set br0 up
for trunk in 3 4; do
    for vlan in 10 20; do
        ip link add link eno$trunk name eno$trunk.$vlan type vlan id $vlan
        ip link set eno$trunk.$vlan master br0
        bridge vlan add vid $vlan pvid untagged dev eno$trunk.$vlan
        bridge vlan del vid 1 dev eno$trunk.$vlan
        ip link set eno$trunk.$vlan up
    done
done
bridge vlan del vid 1 dev br0 self
```

2nd

```
ip link add br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
ip link set br0 up
for trunk in 3 4; do
    ip link set eno$trunk master br0
    for vlan in 10 20; do
        bridge vlan add vid $vlan tagged dev eno$trunk
    done
    bridge vlan del vid 1 dev eno$trunk
    ip link set eno$trunk up
done
bridge vlan del vid 1 dev br0 self
```

As the above two cases or similar,
Is it possible to communicate with each vlan band through the br0 interface of the Linux device by not consuming real IP or using only one?

Comment: These work in different layers, so this doesn't make much sense to me. You should explain what you are trying to achieve and why you are asking this (beware of https://xyproblem.info/ )

Comment: @A.B Sorry for the late edit article, It took a lot of time to check and test what I'm aiming for. and I also tried configuring the vlan in 2 cases using the method that I found in another post you answered.

Comment: I still don't know why you need to do this. I can only tell that setup 1 doesn't require vlan_filtering or to configure bridge port vlans,  because the bridge never sees any VLAN tagged frame for this case. In both cases, there's no need of an IP. a switch or bridge doesn't require an IP to operate properly (and the switch1 isn't a mere switch, it's probably a so-called layer 3 switch: switch+router).